# Splitting a string in java using (?<=\\D)(?=\\d)

Tags: java, arrays, string

So I'm using the following to split up a string:

```
String string_to_separate = coordinateStrings.get(i);   
String [] separated_string = string_to_separate.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)");
```

Where he coordinateStrings is a list of coordinate strings that tell where a queen is on a nxn chess board.
So for example, let's say one of the strings is 'a4', I know the

```
(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)
```

part of the code will split it up to 'a' and '4'.
My question is, how does one take the 'a' to know there's a queen in col 'a' and in row '4'. So like if I get another string read in that has a piece at location 'a8', I would know that there are 2 queens that can attack one another.
I'm just not sure if the (?<=\D)(?=\d) code makes new arrays or what, and if it makes new arrays then how would I create something to access those new arrays.

Notes: There's always going to be a letter that comes first, and once the letters in the string ends the rest would be numbers.

Comment: You need another object to represent the state of your board. `string_to_separate` isn't going to contain that information.

Comment: Hello it looks like you are using a naming convention that is part of either php or c,c++. I suggest you follow the Java naming convention for helpers to understand you. The naming convention is specified here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html